# Will I still be able to open code from an older version of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, c++

I am currently downloading Visual Studio 2019 in the middle of a project. Will I be able to open code from Visual Studio 2017 using Visual Studio 2019, or will I have to do it all again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will I be able to open code from VS 2017 using VS 2019, or will I have to do it all again?

Visual Studio typically does not have a problem opening a solution from a previous edition.  This means your a solution made with Visual Studio 2017 will open without a problem in Visual Studio 2019.

Solution files for Visual Studio used to be specific for the version that created them.  Based on my experience of having a Visual Studio 2019 solution, and being able to open it with Visual Studio 2013, seems like that is no longer the case.

On a separate note, you might want to make sure you target the newer versions of the Platform Toolset, but Visual Studio 2019 can also target previous versions.

> can you elaborate on what you mean by targeting newer versions of the
>   c++ compiler? Is this not what I'm doing by downloading 2019?

Your project is currently set to target whatever version you have selected within Visual Studio 2017.  It will continue to target that current version unless you change it.  There is documentation on Microsoft's website, if you do a search for Platform Toolset, you will find that documentation on how to change the project's setting.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you will have no issues.  Visual Studio and its languages are typically backwards compatible.  If there is a compatibility issue, Visual Studio will automatically try to rectify the problem and point out any issues with the IDE or the language.  However, languages rarely change.  However, you should always read any information pre-upgrade and any release notes, to be sure.